# How would I start a formal proof for the conclusion (P → Q) ↔ ¬ (P ∧ ¬ Q) with no premises?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

There are no premises, and I'm doing this in fitch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For proofs involving biconditionals, you often need to prove both directions independently. That is, you'll need to prove (P -> Q) -> ~(P & ~Q) and also ~(P & ~Q) -> (P -> Q). Let's start with the former.

- First, assume (P -> Q). You must derive ~(P & ~Q). Suppose (P & ~Q) for a *reductio* argument. In a *reductio* argument, you suppose something is true in an attempt to derive a contradiction. If you derive a contradiction, then you know what you supposed can't be true, since everything is true or false and nothing is both. That means the negation of what you supposed is true. In this case, that would be ~(P & ~Q), which is what you want to derive. So, assume (P & ~Q) for *reductio* and look for a contradiction. It's not hard to find if you use conjunction elimination to derive P from (P & ~Q). Combining that with (P -> Q) results in Q, which directly contradicts the ~Q you can also derive from (P & ~Q) by using conjunction elimination. In other words, you've derived (Q & ~Q), which is a contradiction. So, your supposition can't be true. Hence, ~(P & ~Q) follows.
- Second, assume ~(P & ~Q). You must derive (P -> Q). When attempting to derive an expression whose main connective is a conditional, you can assume the antecedent, and attempt to derive the consequent. For this case, assume P. Now, you must derive Q using your premise ~(P & ~Q) and newly assumed P. For this case, assume the negation again for *reductio*, i.e. ~Q. Now you can combine P with ~Q using conjunction introduction, resulting in (P & ~Q). Note this contradicts your initial assumption ~(P & ~Q). That is, you've derived [(P & ~Q) & ~(P & ~Q)]. So, your supposition can't be true. That implies Q is true, which is what you needed to prove.
- Third, you've derived (P -> Q) -> ~(P & ~Q) and ~(P & ~Q) -> (P -> Q). All that's left is to combine them with conjunction introduction: [(P -> Q) -> ~(P & ~Q) & ~(P & ~Q) -> (P -> Q)]. Since that's the definition of (P -> Q) <-> ~(P & ~Q), you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose P → Q. For contradiction, suppose P ∧ ¬Q, meaning we have both P and ¬Q. By P → Q and P, we have Q. But this contradicts ¬Q, so we actually have ¬(P ∧ ¬Q).

Conversely, suppose ¬(P ∧ ¬Q). Suppose P. Then, we cannot have ¬Q, as that would imply P ∧ ¬Q, contradicting ¬(P ∧ ¬Q). So we have ¬¬Q, which is equivalent to Q by the law of excluded middle. This was done under the assumption of P, so P → Q.